# Positioning a div from a sidebar to the right border of the window

Tags: css, html, positioning

I'm unable to position a div as I'd like. 
Here's a schema of the layout I'd like to have.

http://cl.ly/1q2s0k283A3M2u2N1b0D [edited]

The red part is the one that poses problem. I want it to go from the left sidebar to the right border of the window.

How can I do ?

Comment: Provide the code you've produced so far. We will not code it for you from scratch.

Comment: Here's a start code : http://jsfiddle.net/umuv4/ Unable to position the menu div...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to make a new answer rather than edit because this is an entirely different method:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8WUr/)

#### Crucial Elements:

- There's a dummy element (`#dummy`) which extends the background color of the menu bar to the right side of the browser window, purely for decorative purposes.
- `#sidebar` is positioned absolutely so that it extends to the bottom of the browser window.
- `#sidebar`, `#content`, and  `#menu` are within #container which has a fixed width and `margin:0 auto` applied so it's centered at all times within the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Some code: http://jsfiddle.net/zZqaM/3/.

Make a container, with a fixed width. Inside, a bar, with a fixed width and a `float: left;`. Next, also inside, a content `div` which floats right, and a header inside, with the fill content `div` width.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I don't want a fixed width for the red part. It should go to the right border of the window regardless of its size.

Comment: You can also define the width of the bar, container and header in percentages, that will also work.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. If you define the container with 80% width, the bar 20% and both the content and the header 60%, it should work, regardless of the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your left bar (a menu one ?) has a fixed width, so here's a working example:

```css
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: blue;
}
#content{
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
#left_bar {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}
#right_bar {
    margin-left: 120px;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
#header_right {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="left_bar">
    </div>
    <div id="right_bar">
        <div id="header_right">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your body has a 400px width applied to it.

Comment: Then you shouldn't refer to the body tag as the "content" when you have a `div#content`

Comment: Right, was an abuse of language. Answer updated to avoid any misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible with absolute positioning!

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bJWkr/)

You can specify how much whitespace you want between the left side of the browser window and the sidebar by modifying the last property:

```css
#sidebar,
#red {
    left:20px; /* change this to anything, change to 0 if none is desired  */
}​
```

Comment: You're close to what I mean, except that I can't position the sidebar absolutely. Here's an improved schema : http://cl.ly/1q2s0k283A3M2u2N1b0D

Comment: @hugo Why can't you position it absolutely?

Comment: It's contained in another div which has to be centered (with margin:auto). Here's a start code : http://jsfiddle.net/umuv4/

Comment: @hugo You might be surprised to find out it's possible to do both positioning absolutely _and_ centering in this way. Allow me to re-edit my answer.

Comment: I really don't know how it is possible. It would be great if you could show me on your jsfiddle :-) Thanks a lot !

Comment: @hugo Please review my other, new answer for the demo.